# Cannot load JSON in jquery with Phonegap

Tags: jquery, json, cordova

I am trying with varius event, version but i cannot load in init to page one json.

I have 3 files html(index + other+js)  and 1 WS index.html is phonegap standard file and with 4 links and  other file are this:
I am using phonegap 2.9.0, jquery-1.11.0 and jquery.mobile-1.4.2
html file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
      </head>
    <body >

<div data-role="page" id="tintos" data-add-back-btn="true"  data-cache="false">
    <div data-role="content">

    <ul id="vino-list" data-role="listview"  data-theme="a" data-divider-theme="e" data-filter="true"  data-filter-placeholder="Buscar Vinos..."  data-inset="true"  class="tinto">

    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/list.js"> </script>

</body>
</html>
```

And js file contain ajax JSON:

```
var serviceURL = "http://www.domain.com/ws/prueba.php";
$.support.cors = true;
$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
var employees;

$('#tintos').bind('pageinit', function(event) {
    getTintoList();
});
$('#tintos').bind('mobileinit', function(event) {
    getTintoList();
});
$('#tintos').bind('deviceready', function(event) {
    getTintoList();
});
$.getJSON(serviceURL, {
    success:function(data){
                alert("Working");
        data = evalJSON(data);
    }, error: function() { alert("Error"); }
});
function getTintoList() {
        alert('READY!');     
      var output = $('#vino-list').text('Loading data...');
      var vino=locationVars('TIPO'); 
            $.ajax({
                url: serviceURL,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                data: data
                jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
                timeout: 25000,
                success: function(data, status){
                    output.empty();
                    $.each(data, function(i,item){

                       var landmark = '<li><a href="detalleVino.html?ID=' + item.id_vino + '" data-id=' + item.id_vino + ' data-role="button"  data-theme="b"><h3>' 
                       + item.nombre + '</h3>' 
                       + '<h3 align="right">'+item.precio + '</h3>' 
                       + '<p>'+item.denominacion + '</p></a></li>';
                            output.append(landmark);
                        alert("Cargado");
                        $('#vino-list').listview('refresh'); 
                    });
                },
                error: function(){
                    output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
                    navigator.notification.confirm(
                        'Something went wrong. Would you like to retry?',
                        yourCallback,
                        'Error',
                        'No,Yes'
                    );
                }
            });
}
```

Code of WS is:

```
<?php
include($DIRCONF . 'JSON.php');
$tipo=$_GET['TIPO'];
$ida='OK';
$json = new Services_JSON;

//Las varibales de conexion y bbdd las recuperamos de las constantes de config.ini.php
$conexion = mysql_connect(SERVIDOR_MYSQL, USUARIO_MYSQL, PASSWORD_MYSQL);
mysql_select_db(BASE_DATOS, $conexion);

//Obtenemos lista de amigos con amistad confirmada


$que = "SELECT id_vino,nombre,precio,nombre as denominacion FROM `VINOS` WHERE `VINO`.estado=1 AND `VINO`.codRestaurante=1 AND `VINO`.descripcion='$tipo'";
$res = mysql_query($que, $conexion) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
//Cerramos la conexion a la base de datos
mysql_close($conexion);

//Devolvemos el valor

//header("Content-type: application/json");
echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($data) . ');';

?>
```

The WS is been tested with RESTClient and is right when json is invocate show:

"number of jsonCallBack" + ([{"id_vino":"2","nombre":"Martinez la cuesta","precio":"22","denominacion":"DO La Rioja"}]);

I execute in navigator and i need push F5 for see JSON but in Android not saw anything

I don't know how resolved this problem of if this aplication is posible do with phonegap.

I have tried with  last version of cordova too, but same result.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Check your serviceURL, it is not working.

Comment: Yes is working i have put data in response, url in this codenot is real domain.

Comment: can you show here your url..?

Comment: if i use setTimeout , i can refresh 1st page, but if index has link to other 2ns page in this page don't refresh, this is my case. in 2nd page don't load ready event?

Comment: Ved why do you want know URL, i have check is right , i put you what data give back this URL.

Comment: check your json data encoded or not in service side.

Comment: ok i have update with ws code

Answer (score 0):

I answer my question, i need put in links rel="external"

now are working